# How to return sObject collection variable or collection variable to flow?

Tags: flow, multi-select

I have an object with a multipicklist field. I need to filter that object based on some values chosen in the flow.Let multipicklist field may contain A;B;C etc. and if user choose B,I need to create a dynamic choice with field that contains B.  Since 'contain' doesn't work with multipicklist field, I need to use apex @InvocableMethod or Plugin method  to filter the object.

1. How can I return the filtered list of objects to the flow to create a dynamic choice. ie how to return sobject collection variable to flow.
2. If it is not possible, Is there any way to pass collection variable from apex class to flow.
3. Is there any other method to solve multipicklist('contain' doesn't work) issue.